# c backslash ignored in comment

Tags: c, comments, backslash

I am confused by a behavior in C language where a backslash at the end of a comments is ignored as shown below. As you can see after the comment, 
"comment 2: Dummy" there is a backslash at the end. What I am expecting is a compilation error but didn't get any. I am using Greenhills compiler. But this behavior is only with the "\" character. If I use something else the compiler generates and error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x =0;
int y =2;


#define MACRO(x) (x+y)\
/*comment 1: Do addition of two operations*/ \
               +\
            (x*y)

/*comment 2: Dummy */\  <=============== Backslash at the end 

#define MACRO1(y) (x+y)\
/*comment 3: Do Sub of two operations*/ \
            -\
            (x*y)

int main()
{
    x = MACRO(x);
    printf("value is : %d",x);
    y = MACRO1(y);
    printf("value is : %d",y);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, a ``\`` at the end of a macro indicates that there's another line in the macro so the compiler see's this as a valid syntax.

Comment: yeah. But this is not at the  end of a macro but at the end of a comment

Comment: It is outside the comment. Comment is inside ``/* COMMENT */``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *backslash ignored in comment*

Two things:

- It is not *in* comment
- It is ought to be ignored, no wonder.

To elaborate, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.4.9

> Except within a character constant, a string literal, or a comment, the characters `/*`
>   introduce a comment. The contents of such a comment are examined only to identify
>   multibyte characters and to find the characters `*/` that terminate it.

So, in your case, the `\` is outside the comment and is considered part of the source code.

Now, considering that *stray* backslash, as mentioned in the translation phase, chapter §5.1.1.2/p2

> Each instance of a backslash character (`\`) immediately followed by a new-line
>   character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines. Only the last backslash on any physical source line shall be eligible for being part
>   of such a splice. [....]

So, in your case, the stray backslash and the followed newline is *effectively* removed while reaching the *actual* compilation phase, so there's no error there.

[You can read more about the compilation phases here.](https://calleerlandsson.com/the-four-stages-of-compiling-a-c-program/)

Comment: @DeepuD em...why's that? What did the answer say? You don't expect error for something which does not exist, right?

Comment: Thank you @SouravGhosh for the quotation from C standard.

Answer (score 1):

In [c](/questions/tagged/c), to write a multi-line macro, each statement ends with`\`. In your second line the comment is defined inside the `/* COMMENT */`. So anything outside that is a syntax, and `\` is valid one.

This is why your compiler is ok with the `\`.

Extra `\` are irrelevant and compiler just ignores as there's no statement to come inside.

You can add as much `\` as you want and the code your compiler generates will be the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x =0;
int y =2;


#define MACRO(x) (x+y)\
/*comment 1: Do addition of two operations*/ \
               +\
            (x*y)
 \
\
\
\

int main()
{
    x = MACRO(x);
    printf("value is : %d",x);
    return (0);
}
```

And the generated **code:**

```
    .file   "Untitled1.c"
    .globl  _x
    .bss
    .align 4
_x:
    .space 4
    .globl  _y
    .data
    .align 4
_y:
    .long   2
    .def    ___main;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section .rdata,"dr"
LC0:
    .ascii "value is : %d\0"
    .text
    .globl  _main
    .def    _main;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_main:
LFB10:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $16, %esp
    call    ___main
    movl    _x, %edx
    movl    _y, %eax
    leal    (%edx,%eax), %ecx
    movl    _x, %edx
    movl    _y, %eax
    imull   %edx, %eax
    addl    %ecx, %eax
    movl    %eax, _x
    movl    _x, %eax
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl    $LC0, (%esp)
    call    _printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE10:
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 5.3.0"
    .def    _printf;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
```

Comment: OK. I agree with this explanation for the comments with in the macro definition, viz. "comment 1" and "comment 3". But my concern is "comment 2". It is not part of any comment but contains a backslash. so finally in the preprocessing stage the comments would be removed and the "\" would be left there. So do a single "\" is a valid C statement ?

Comment: @DeepuD yes. I edited to show that no matter how many ``\`` you add, the generated code by your compiler is the same.

Comment: Thank you @Tony Tannous for the great explanation.